Django Rest Framework - ListCreateAPIView - How to filter + aggregate + create multiple objects inside def perform_create
Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated please!
Basically I have a model called Transaction and is linked to the User model using a ForeignKey.
I would like to filter all transactions made today, per user, and then I want to aggregate their sales by summing the transactions per user, and then based on this sum, I would want to calculate 10% of it and create a new transaction (basically today's interest earned)
I have tried to make it work inside inside serializers.py
class UserTransactionFilterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
username = serializers.CharField(read_only = True)
id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only = True)
agg_amt_btc = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
trans = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)

# Gets transaction data using UserTransactionSerializer
def get_trans(self, obj):
    user = obj
    print(user)
    today = timezone.now().date()
    my_trans_qs = user.transaction_set.filter(trans_date__date=today)
    return TransactionUserInlineSerializer(my_trans_qs, many=True, context = self.context).data

# Aggregates the trans amount (sum and avg)
def get_agg_amt_btc(self, obj):
    user = obj
    print(user)
    today = timezone.now().date()
    my_trans_qs = user.transaction_set.filter(trans_date__date=today)
    return my_trans_qs.aggregate(sum_btc = Sum('trans_amt_btc'), avg_btc = Avg('trans_amt_btc'))


def create(self,obj):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    for user in User.objects.filter(transaction__trans_date__date=today).distinct():

        total_transactions = user.transaction_set.aggregate(sum_btc = Sum('trans_amt_btc'))['sum_btc']

        print(user)
        transaction_amount = total_transactions * Decimal('0.1')
        print(transaction_amount)
        
        with transaction.atomic():
            Transaction.objects.create(owner=user, trans_amt_btc=transaction_amount)

    return user

Which works! but it bypasses all validations when I do:
Transaction.objects.create(owner=user,trans_amt_btc=transaction_amount) 

The problem is that in the above objects.create method, some fields are not mentioned.
For example there is a field trans_status which is found in the Transaction model (shown below) which has null=False and blank=False But, when the object gets created, it has these fields as null instead of giving me an error
Any idea how I can implement this inside a view where I am sure the validation can happen?
Here are the fields of my Transaction model looks like for your reference:
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, default = 1, null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL) #related_name defaults to transaction_set

trans_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
trans_amt_btc = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=12, max_digits=24,blank=False, null=False)

trans_type = models.CharField(choices= TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=24, blank=False, null=False)
trans_reason = models.CharField(choices= TRANSACTION_REASON_CHOICES, max_length=24, blank=False, null=False)
trans_mode = models.CharField(choices= TRANSACTION_MODE_CHOICES, max_length=24, blank=False, null=False)
trans_status = models.CharField(choices= TRANSACTION_STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=24, blank=False, default="APPROVED")

note = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)

Below is my attempt at adding it in the view, where I hope I can perform the required validations which is not working:
class UserTransactionCommissionView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
queryset = User.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserTransactionFilterSerializer

def perform_create(self,serializer):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    for user in list(User.objects.filter(transaction__trans_date__date=today).distinct()):

        total_transactions = user.transaction_set.aggregate(sum_btc = Sum('trans_amt_btc'))['sum_btc']

        print(total_transactions)
        
        total_transactions = serializer.validated_data.get('trans_amt_btc')

        
        transaction_amount = total_transactions * Decimal('0.1')
        print(transaction_amount)

        serializer.save(owner=user)

        
        # with transaction.atomic():
        #     Transaction.objects.create(owner=user, trans_amt_btc=transaction_amount)

    return user


It's a good idea, If you create file named "managers" to handle your queries in it. looks like you have trouble with your queries, right? And if you share the UserTransaction model will be a great view of your code.

Hey,
For now there is only a Transaction model which I shared in the code
I am not sure that the problem is with the query itself (because the same code worked inside the serializer, which I am trying to avoid), I'm guessing I am doing something wrong inside the perform_create method

Adding it in the view is the right way to go, but I think you're just missing another serializer. You should create the below serializer in order to have all the needed fields:
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['owner', 'trans_amt_btc'] # Add other required fields here

Now you need to use that serializer inside the perform_create as such:
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    for user in User.objects.filter(transaction__trans_date__date=today).distinct():
        total_transactions = user.transaction_set.filter(trans_date__date=today).aggregate(sum_btc=Sum('trans_amt_btc'))['sum_btc']
        if total_transactions:
            transaction_amount = total_transactions * Decimal('0.1')
            transaction_data = {
                'owner': user,
                'trans_amt_btc': transaction_amount
                 # Add other fields here
            }
            transaction_serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=transaction_data) # <= Call the new serializer
            if transaction_serializer.is_valid(): # <= Do the validation
                transaction_serializer.save()
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(transaction_serializer.errors)


Just a minor comment, inside transaction_data
'owner' : user.pk should be user instead of 'owner': user
